# Simulating Mac Mouse Events beyond CGCreateMouseEvent

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, iokit

I've been successfully using CG mouse events to simulate mouse down/drag/up events using a specialized hardware controller.  However, I come across some applications in which using these CG mouse events has no effect- that is, I can click and drag the actual mouse to change controls within a certain area of the application, but simulating these exact same movements using CGCreateMouseEvent (tried posting to HID system state and CombinedSession state) does not work.

Perhaps these apps are listening specifically for a mouse/touchpad hardware device?  Is there any way to more "realistically " simulate mouse events so that these app think the actual mouse/touchpad is dragging?

Comment: Can you give an example of an application where this isn't working?

Comment: The ProTools Surround Panner to be specific...

Comment: ProTools, eh? Good luck... God only knows what they're doing, although I'm surprised that sending events via the HID subsystem isn't working. I generally think of that as being pretty low level.